# How to Name a Path in TemporalData?

Tags: list-manipulation, data, associations, time-series, finance

Preamble:
I am working with stock prices and need to perform calculations on them. And then extract the information for further calculations.

`TimeSeries`/`TemporalData` make calculation easier, but I find it difficult to pull out data for further calculation (detailed below)

It is easy to pull out data from a list of `Associations` however it is not easy performing timeseries type calculations on them (day-on-day price difference for example).

Let us look at an example:

```
(* import prices *)
rawData = N@ImportString["Date\tAPPLE\tIBM\tCAT
2023-05-04\t1100\t56\t80
2023-05-05\t1115\t58\t70
2023-05-08\t1200\t80\t60
2023-05-09\t400\t40\t180
", "TSV"];
```

| Date | APPLE | IBM | CAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-04 | 1100. | 56. | 80. |
| 2023-05-05 | 1115. | 58. | 70. |
| 2023-05-08 | 1200. | 80. | 60. |
| 2023-05-09 | 400. | 40. | 180. |

```
(* extract information *)
header = rawData[[1]];
body = rawData[[2 ;;]];
stockNames = header[[2 ;;]];

date = body[[All ;;, 1]];
apple = body[[All ;;, 2]];
ibm = body[[All ;;, 3]];
cat = body[[All ;;, 4]];

(* create a timeseries for each stock *)
appleTS = TimeSeries[Transpose@{date, apple}, TemporalRegularity -> True];
ibmTS = TimeSeries[Transpose@{date, ibm}, TemporalRegularity -> True];
catTS = TimeSeries[Transpose@{date, cat}, TemporalRegularity -> True];

(* perform operations on each of the time series *)    
prices = {appleTS, ibmTS, catTS};
differences = Differences /@ prices;
stdev = MovingMap[StandardDeviation, #, Quantity[2, "Events"]] & /@ differences;


(* combine the output *)    
stocksRaw =
    TimeSeriesThread[
      Identity,
      {prices, differences, stdev},
      ResamplingMethod -> None
    ];

(* name the columns that each operation was done on *)    
stocks =
    TemporalData[
      stocksRaw,
      "MetaInformation" -> {"ComponentNames" -> {"prices", "differences", "stdev"}}
    ];
```

`TemporalData` is great it is easy to perform calculations and I don't need to worry about padding of dates or making sure time is sorted. I can also see a granular detail what was calculated eg, I can see the difference in price on 2023-05-05:

```
stocks["PathComponent", "differences"]["SliceData", "2023-05-05"]
```

> {15., 2., -10.}

and it takes care of data that gets shortened:

```
stocks["PathComponent", "stdev"]["SliceData", "2023-05-05"]
```

> {Missing[], Missing[], Missing[]}

However, If I want to pull up data about `IBM` I need to remember it was the second column/ indexed at 2 and so need to do

```
stocks["Path", 2]
```

> {{3892147200, {56., Missing[], Missing[]}}, {3892233600, {58., 2.,
> Missing[]}}, {3892492800, {80., 22.,
> 14.1421}}, {3892579200, {40., -40., 43.8406}}}

**Question: How can I use TemporalData (or another method) so that I can get my data using something like**

`stock["IBM"]`

> {{3892147200, {56., Missing[], Missing[]}}, {3892233600, {58., 2.,
> Missing[]}}, {3892492800, {80., 22.,
> 14.1421}}, {3892579200, {40., -40., 43.8406}}}

`stock["IBM","stdev"]`

> {{3892147200, Missing[]}, {3892233600, Missing[]}, {3892492800,
> 14.1421}, {3892579200, 43.8406}}

`stock["IBM","stdev","2023-05-09"]`

> {43.8406}

Being able to rename the paths in `TimeSeries` would be an analagous solution.

A workaround with a helper function like `f[stockname_]:=First@FirstPosition[stockNames, stockname]` seems unsatisfactory as you still need to remember your indexing as you write large code and be careful not to move columns around.

---

An alternative solution would be to return output as a list of associations. However, it is difficult to work on lists of associations as I need to pad dates with `Missing[]` to keep a regular shape and calculation of things like `Differences` is tricky as you need to pull up the previous time-step row.

For example output along the lines

```
{<|"Date" -> "2023-05-04", "APPLE" -> 1100, "IBM" -> 56, "CAT" -> 80, 
  "APPLEdifference" -> "Missing[]", "IBMdifference" -> "Missing[]", 
  "CATdifference" -> "Missing[]", "APPLEstdev" -> "Missing[]", 
  "IBMstdev" -> "Missing[]", 
  "CATstdev" -> "Missing[]"|>, <|"Date" -> "2023-05-05", 
  "APPLE" -> 1115, "IBM" -> 58, "CAT" -> 70, "APPLEdifference" -> 15, 
  "IBMdifference" -> 2, "CATdifference" -> -10, 
  "APPLEstdev" -> "Missing[]", "IBMstdev" -> "Missing[]", 
  "CATstdev" -> "Missing[]"|>, <|"Date" -> "2023-05-08", 
  "APPLE" -> 1200, "IBM" -> 80, "CAT" -> 60, "APPLEdifference" -> 85, 
  "IBMdifference" -> 22, "CATdifference" -> -10, "APPLEstdev" -> 49.5,
   "IBMstdev" -> 14.14, "CATstdev" -> 0.|>, <|"Date" -> "2023-05-09", 
  "APPLE" -> 400, "IBM" -> 40, "CAT" -> 180, 
  "APPLEdifference" -> -800, "IBMdifference" -> -40, 
  "CATdifference" -> 120, "APPLEstdev" -> 625.79, "IBMstdev" -> 43.84,
   "CATstdev" -> 91.92|>}
```

[image]

is easy to use, you can do
`anotherOutput[[All, {"Date", "IBM", "IBMdifference", "IBMstdev"}]]`

> {<|"Date" -> "2023-05-04", "IBM" -> 56,
> "IBMdifference" -> "Missing[]",
> "IBMstdev" -> "Missing[]"|>, <|"Date" -> "2023-05-05", "IBM" -> 58,
> "IBMdifference" -> 2,
> "IBMstdev" -> "Missing[]"|>, <|"Date" -> "2023-05-08", "IBM" -> 80,
> "IBMdifference" -> 22,
> "IBMstdev" -> 14.14|>, <|"Date" -> "2023-05-09", "IBM" -> 40,
> "IBMdifference" -> -40, "IBMstdev" -> 43.84|>}

`Select[anotherOutput, #Date == "2023-05-08" &][[All, {"Date",  "IBMstdev"}]]`

> {<|"Date" -> "2023-05-08", "IBMstdev" -> 14.14|>}

Comment: I could add support for:

 td = TemporalData[RandomReal[1, {3, 2}], {0}, 
   MetaInformation -> {"PathNames" -> {"a", "b", "c"}}];

To retrieve:

td["Path", "b"]

td["TemporalDataPath", "b"]

And when the list of paths is to be returned it would be an association if the path names are specified...
Also, this would only apply to TemporalData as TimeSeries is a single path object.

Comment: Glad to hear from you! I've been reading all your previous TimeSeries answers and found them very helpful!

Comment: "when the list of paths is to be returned it would be an association if the path names are specified" This sounds like the desired behavior as you can then manipulate and call those paths without worrying about indexing etc.

Comment: Very well then.